# Downloading VCF file created by PHP with Safari doesn't work, all ok with Android and Windows

Tags: iphone, safari, vcf-vcard

This link works EVERYWHERE: https://www.autobackoffice.com/vcard.php

And this is the content of the file:

```
<?php
  header('Content-Type: text/x-vcard; charset=utf-8;');
  header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=vcard.vcf"');
  echo "BEGIN:VCARD\n";
  echo "VERSION:3.0\n";
  echo "N:My Name\n";
  echo "FN:Yet another Name\n";
  echo "URL:https://www.google.com\n";
  echo "ORG:Organization\n";
  echo "EMAIL:info@google.com\n";
  echo "PHOTO;VALUE#URI;TYPE#JPG:https://www.autobackoffice.com/mv/media/logohp.jpg\n";
  echo "TEL;TYPE=voice:1234567890\n";
  echo "ADR;TYPE#WORK,PREF:;;Long Way Avenue\n";
  echo "REV:2022-01-26T12:13:14Z\n";
  echo "END:VCARD\n";
?>
```

But if I simply "embed it" here:

```
<a href='vcard.php' download='test.vcf'>Click to download</a>
```

then it doesn't work on iPhone/Safari.
You can test it here: https://www.autobackoffice.com/vcard2.php

The content of vcard2.php is EXACTLY that single `a href` line above.